# Pick an element from each matrix columns

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix `m` and a vector `v`. The vector specifies which element I need in each of `m`'s columns.  The length of `v` equals the number of columns in `m`.  I tried `apply(m,2, FUN)` but couldn't come up with the right function to do the trick.  My data and vector are defined bellow.

```
set.seed(12)
m <- matrix(sample(1:100,28),4)
v <- c(3,2,2,3,1,4,3)
```

The result I want is a vector `vv`:

```
vv <- c(93,4,1,23,39,82,85)
```

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix elements may also be indexed via a 2 column matrix. Such a matrix determines which elements (#row, #column) you want to extract.
In your case these are (3,1), (2,2), (2,3), (3,4), etc., i.e. (v[1], 1), (v[2], 2), and so on. Thus, this is a solution:

```
set.seed(12)
m <- matrix(sample(1:100,28),4)
v <- c(3,2,2,3,1,4,3)

m[cbind(v,seq_along(v))]
## [1] 93  4  1 23 39 82 85
```

Comment: Excellent, I thought of something similar but wasn't sure I could pass the index to m in this fashion.  To the point and simple love it.